# hibernate setter on domain object not called

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate

I'm trying to POST a request like this:

```
<event><name>test</name><description>event description</description></event>
```

however in mySQL table, my table projects displays:

```
id | description       | name
1  | event description | NULL
```

I can't figure out why setter for event name won't get called even though description works.  Below is how I'm calling my methods

resource class post method:

```
...
//add event a method in my service class
//getEventName is null, getDescription gets description
myservice.addEvent(event.getEventName(),event.getDescription());
...
```

domain class:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "events" )
@XmlRootElement(name = "event")
public class Event {
    @XmlAttribute
    private Long id;
    private String eventName;
    private String description;

    public Event() {
        // this form used by Hibernate
    }

    public Event(String eventName, String description) {
        this.description = description;
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private void setId(Long id) {
        System.out.println("id " + id); //prints id correctly
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="name")
    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        System.out.println("here event" + eventName); //prints nothing
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    @Column(name="description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        System.out.println("here desc " + description); //prints correctly
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Output in console:

```
here desc event description
id 3
```

What is causing my setEventName to be ignored? No errors are showing up in console

Comment: Your property is named `eventName`. Your XML uses an element named `name`. That doesn't match. And you have no JAXB annotation customizing the XML element name to use instead of `eventName`.